# changing the names of files within a directory

Tags: filenames

I have few files under a particular directory.
These are the files

```
idex.1.ebwt  idex.2.ebwt  idex.3.ebwt  idex.4.ebwt  idex.rev.1.ebwt  idex.rev.2.ebwt
```

I want to change the names of the file from `idex` to `index` keeping the rest of the name same. Basically I want to replace `idex` with `index`

Any one line command?

Comment: Try searching the site before asking such as basic Q. Search phrases such as "rename files" will give you many ways to do what you want.

Comment: got it. sorry for the trouble thanks for the reply

Answer (score 2):

You could do this with a simple `for`-loop and some shell magic:

```
for file in idex.*; do
    mv "$file" "index${file#idex}"
done
```

Yes, you could also put this into one line. ;)

`${var#pattern}` evaluates to `$var` with a leading `pattern` removed (where `pattern` is a `glob(7)` pattern).  There exist four variants of this (POSIX compliant):

1. `${var#pattern}` evaluates to `$var` with a leading `pattern` removed (non-greedy).
2. `${var##pattern}` evaluates to `$var` with a leading `pattern` removed (greedy).
3. `${var%pattern}` evaluates to `$var` with a trailing `pattern` removed (non-greedy).
4. `${var%%pattern}` evaluates to `$var` with a trailing `pattern` removed (greedy).

Difference to non-greedy and greedy is that if you have for example `$var` set to `foo.bar.baz`, `${var%.*}` will evaluate to `foo.bar`, but `${var%%.*}` will evaluate to `foo`.  This is because `${var%.*}` will search for the *shortest* pattern matching `.*` (thus from *last* `.` to end), where `${var%%.*}` will search for the *longest* one (thus from *first* `.` to end).

You can help yourself memorizing which version are the non-greedy and the greedy ones simply with memorizing that the *longer* (`#` resp. `%` twice) search for a *longer* match.

Comment: Please try searching the site before adding more answers that provide the same general solutions that have already been captured before. Renaming files have been written up dozens of times already.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a major linux distribution or have the standard `util-linux` package installed, this one-liner code should do what you want.

```
rename idex index idex*
```

Comment: Which rename command? `rename` varies by OS and some can even have different non-compatible alternatives for the `rename` command.

Comment: Isn't `rename` part of the standard `util-linux` package which is common for most major distros?

Comment: _Linux_ distros, indeed.

Comment: @Chirag64 Please try searching the site before adding more answers that provide the same general solutions that have already been captured before.

Comment: Yes, it is in `util-linux` but there is also a `rename` that comes with `perl`, which is also very common. Which one is `/usr/bin/rename` by default is up to the distro. In Debian, it is the `perl` version.